# My computer tries to connect to an old wireless router

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I'm not tech savvy, but I use Windows 10 with a Realtek 802.11 b/g/n Wi-Fi Adapter on an HP laptop. Sometimes I cannot connect to certain public wifi routers. It has happened twice or so at a McDonald's within a Walmart mostly (I'm not sure it happens in other public wifi spots).

All I know to do is run the Troubleshoot Problems feature to try to fix the internet connection, and sometimes I will get a message that I have my computer set to manually connect to restaurant's public wifi that I was near the night before but never connected to. In fact, I was connected to the internet at a location too far down the street to even connect, I would think.

I don't see Google articles about this, but I do recall once just running the Troubleshoot Problems a couple of times and my computer kind of righted itself, I guess.

Can anyone tell me why this is and how to fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this link will answer your question as that is what causing it -

http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-delete-or-forget-wireless-network-profiles-windows-10

in summary -

When you connect to broadcasting or even to a hidden wireless network in Windows 10, the operating system creates a profile for that connection, in which it stores information like its SSID (the name of the network) and its security details (like the password and the encryption type it uses). But what if you decide you don't want your PC or device to remember a certain wireless connection? In such a case, you must delete its network profile and forget that Wi-Fi network. In this guide we will show you how to do that:

In order to forget a wireless network in Windows 10, you can use the Settings app. To begin, open the Settings with a click or tap on its shortcut from the Start Menu.

Inside the Settings app, click or tap on Network & Internet.

The second option from the left of the Network & Internet window is called Wi-Fi. Click or tap on it.

Then, on the right side of the Wi-Fi settings window, look for the settings section called simply Wi-Fi. It should be the first one you see. In it, click or tap on “Manage known networks”.

The “Manage known networks” settings section opens and, in it, you will see the complete list with all the Wi-Fi networks your Windows 10 PC or device knows.

Click or tap on the wireless network that you want your Windows 10 PC or device to forget. This will make Windows 10 display two options: Properties and Forget. The Properties button will open a list with details about that Wi-Fi network. However, that’s not what we’re looking for. What we want is to delete the wireless network's stored profile and forget all its connection details, so what you must do is click or tap on Forget.

After you click or tap on the Forget button, Windows 10 immediately removes the wireless network from the list of known networks. If there are other networks you want your Windows 10 device to forget, repeat this procedure. Otherwise, you can simply close the Settings app.

### p.s.

Sometimes even if you dont successfully connect to a wifi - just by clicking on it creates a profile for it and anytime you are close enough to the wifi network, windows 10 will try to connect to it! ...and so you can delete such a wifi network as described above.

Also be careful when you connect to free networks- very risky re your security and your identity may be stolen etc :)

Comment: Please develop your answer. The link you shared might be dead in a few years and then it won't be useful to anyone.

Comment: Please reference and properly cite all relevant information in your answer

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: This was so helpful. Thank you so much, David. I followed the steps and found the mysterious wifi router in that list. Last night, I went to Starbucks and used their wifi, then went back to the McD's and did not have any troubles. I guess the computer just gets stuck on an old connection that I unwittingly made, as you mentioned. Thanks, again!